# Generic Types and Interfaces Java

Tags: java, generics, interface

Having these classes and interfaces..

```
public interface Shape;

public interface Line extends Shape

public interface ShapeCollection< Shape>

public class MyClass implements ShapeCollection< Line>

List< ShapeCollection< Shape>> shapeCollections = new LinkedList< ShapeCollection< Shape>>();
```

When I try to add an instance of `MyClass` to the `shapeCollections`, Eclipse still asks to let `MyClass` implement `ShapeCollection< Shape>` when it already does since it implements `ShapeCollection< Line>` beeing `Line` an extension to `Shape`. I've tried to change to `ShapeCollection< T extends Shape>` with no results. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `Line` being a subtype of `Shape` does not mean that `ShapeCollection<Line>` is a subtype of `ShapeCollection<Shape>`. I believe you'll need something like `List<? extends ShapeCollection<? extends Shape>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared type parameters whose *name* is `Shape`, `Line` etc. You have not declared a *bound*. That is, these two declarations are the same:

```
public interface ShapeCollection<Shape> // generic parameter called Shape
public interface ShapeCollection<T>  // generic parameter called T
```

But what you *want* is:

```
public interface ShapeCollection<T extends Shape> // generic parameter bound to Shape
```

When it comes to using it, if I read your question literally you are trying to add a `MyClass` to a `List<ShapeCollection<Shape>>`, but `MyClass` is not a collection of `Shape` but a collection of `Line` and `Line` extends `Shape`, you you must use `? extends Shape` as the type, not `Shape`:

```
List<ShapeCollection<? extends Shape>> shapeCollections = new LinkedList<ShapeCollection<? extends Shape>>();
shapeCollections.add(new MyClass()); // should work
```

This is because `Collection<Line>` is **not a subclass** of `Collection<Shape>`: Generics is not like class hierarchies.

Comment: But for example MyClass that implements ShapesCollection<Line> does let me implements its methods because it accepts Line as a Shape. And I already tried that, but thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: Yea that did it, thanks a lot. I thought beeing Line a extension of Shape this was acceptable. So writing ? extends Shape basically says that it accepts anything that extends Shape?

Comment: `Collection<? extends Shape>` means it's a `Collection` whose type is either `Shape` or any subclass of `Shape`. But the key takeaway here is the last sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the declarations you put `MyClass` does not implement `ShapeCollection<Line>`. And even if it did, it wouldn't matter. You can put only things that extends `Shape` and not things that extend `ShapeCollection<Shape>`